# How can I correct the error: `x` must be a string of length 1?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, url

I want to download tables on many similar URLs.

These URLs differed only in a small part (numbers), so I put the differing numbers (2270100023, 2270100080, 2270100122) in an excel file (test_no.xlsx) and created a loop to create a series of URLs. it was very successful up to this point.

```
no_list <- read_excel("X:/zhang/R/markdown/test/test_no.xlsx")
xpath1 <- '//*[@id="kihonPage"]/div[1]/div[1]/article/section/div[5]'
final_data <- NULL

for (i in no_list)
 {url1 <- paste("https://www.kaigokensaku.mhlw.go.jp/20/index.php?action_kouhyou_detail_024_kihon=true&JigyosyoCd=", i, "-00&ServiceCd=510", sep ="")
 final_data <- rbind(final_data, url1)
}
```

The final_data is a "matrix" "array" like
[final_data I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0fcY.png)

But when I tried to use this loop to download the tables, the program got an error.
**Error: `x` must be a string of length 1**
The code I used is as follows：

```
no_list <- read_excel("X:/zhang/R/markdown/test/test_no.xlsx")
xpath1 <- '//*[@id="kihonPage"]/div[1]/div[1]/article/section/div[5]'
final_data <- NULL

for (i in no_list)
 {url1 <- paste("https://www.kaigokensaku.mhlw.go.jp/20/index.php?action_kouhyou_detail_024_kihon=true&JigyosyoCd=", i, "-00&ServiceCd=510", sep ="")

test <- url1 %>%                # Scrape data
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath=xpath1) %>%
  html_table()

test1 <- test[[1]] # Select table number
final_data <- rbind(final_data, test1)
}
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit challenging to help with this problem without seeing more of the data. I'm not an expert in this area but I had a similar issue looping through URLs with the same error.

My issue was how the URLs were originally stored, which was a list within a tibble. The first item in the tibble passed to the loop was actually all of the URLs in the list. You can check for this specific issue by checking the length: `length(no_list)`. If it comes back as 1, you probably have the same issue. You can either fix the way the URLs are originally stored or access individual URLs by subsetting further: `no_list[[1]][1]` would select the first URL, `no_list[[1]][2]` selects the second, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi user723374, welcome to SO. The thing that makes SO such a valuable resource is the focus on questions that are [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) and answers that can be proven to solve the question at hand. While your answer _might_ solve this issue, there is no way to verify it as the OP did not provide enough information. Please familiarise yourself with [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the bit about well-asked questions. Thanks